# Apk not installed in Android mobile

Tags: android, apk

Debug Apk not installed in mobile, while demo app installed from Playstore in my mobile, code which bought from Codecanyon.

If I unstalled that demo means my apk is installed without any issues..

Even I have changed Package name and Key.

Please advice why I can't install my debug Apk when that demo app installed in my mobile..

Answer (score 0):

Try to install with ***adb***, it will show you the error. like:

```
adb install apk_name.apk
```

If an app with same package name but different key is already installed, you can't update that.

Comment: Hi.. Zeero0, I have tried.. getting error as "A database with the same name already exists"

Comment: Do you have multiple user accounts on your phone? Try to uninstall the apk for all users.

Comment: No.. Only single account.. even I tried in some other mobile too.. maybe the path (folder name) saving video in mobile from the app is same in both App?? Bcoz its whatsapp status video saving app..